# Python search website in google that end with specific word

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-search

I tried to search all websites in Google that end with "gencat.cat".

My code:

```
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {'q': 'gencat.cat'}
html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# containver with all needed data
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
    link = result.a['href'] # or ('.yuRUbf a')['href']
    print(link)
```

**Output that I have**:

The problem is that only a few websites are searched and also it takes some urls without "gencat.cat" in them or repeats pages from the same site:

```
https://web.gencat.cat/ca/inici
https://web.gencat.cat/es/inici/
https://web.gencat.cat/ca/tramits
https://web.gencat.cat/en/inici/index.html
https://govern.cat/
https://govern.cat/salapremsa/
http://www.gencat.es/
http://www.regencos.cat/promocio-variable/preguntes-mes-frequents-sobre-el-coronavirus/
https://tauler.seu.cat/inici.do?idens=1
```

**Output that I want**:

```
https://web.gencat.cat
http://agricultura.gencat.cat
http://cultura.gencat.cat
https://dretssocials.gencat.cat
http://economia.gencat.cat
```

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](https://policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Comment: Hi @StephenOstermiller,  I did not know it, sorry. But I have a coworker condemned to do  very manual job and this could help ease the workload. So... How can I do it and respecte the terms of service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting the top-level domain, you can split the link on all the instances of "/" in the `link` variable.

```
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
link = result.a['href'] # or ('.yuRUbf a')['href']
print(link)

string_splt = link.split("/")
TLD = f"https://{string_splt[2]}"

print(TLD)
```

I am sure there is a better way to bring it all back together but this seems to work. You will also need to handle the duplicates as well.

Comment: Hi A.Patterson, its works but I don't know why only print a few websites, there are some limit using this search?

Comment: There is another parameter of start which, I believe, controls what page you are starting on in the results. It increments by 10. That seems to be the way to get more results.